# How can I create a basic multiplayer server and allow connections from the internet for any basic game (eg: tic tac toe)?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, p2p, multiplayer

I would like to create a server using either php or javascript for the implementation of a multiplayer gaming arena, which would allow users to connect and play games online over the internet. What game they play is not my concern, I just wish to build a server which can efficiently manage and allow the existence of an arena (eg: Garena or Steam).

It doesn't have to be really complicated, the most simplest of implementation guideline would be thoroughly appreciated. I have been researching slowly for over a month now, but I've had no solid understanding of even the most fundamental blocks needed to craft this piece of software. The hints I found, I have added them as tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're looking for is a websocket server.

thats if you want to have a web based server.  I figured as much since you're talking about web scripting.